# Webpack imports with Rails 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a pretty large codebase that I am attempting to migrate from Rails 4 to 5, a major part of this is transitioning off of the asset pipeline to webpack to manage requirements and packages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <% content_for :extra_head_scripts do %>
  <% end %>
  <head>
    <title>Cloverhound</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <%= javascript_pack_tag "application-editor", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application-editor", :media => "all" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
    <%= render partial: "layouts/shared/head_scripts" %>


    <!-- this javascript_tag passes the user's locale to the editor to enable translations -->
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
      I18n.defaultLocale = "<%= I18n.default_locale %>";
      I18n.locale = "<%= current_user.locale.shortcode.to_s %>";
    <% end %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render partial: "shared/svg_sprite" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above file, I am attempting to load the I18n module so that it can be used.

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker');
console.log("Application-Editor");

import Sortable from 'sortablejs';
//var I18n = require('i18n-js');
import I18n from 'i18n';
```

Above is my simple webpack file that properly logs to the chrome console, however, I18n is still undefined. If i attempt to call I18n within application-editor.js, it will also return undefined. However, if i change i18n to i18n-bad or something to that effect, I will get an error saying that the module could not be found. This leads me to believe that my module is being found, but something is going wrong in the process of importing it. I am very new to webpacker so any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please replace the images with real code? It will be more readable for all community.

Comment: Done! Sorry, first stackoverflow post and not quite sure how everything works yet

Comment: No problem man! Try to follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, I didn't see your change yet. Have you edit your post and replace the images to code already?

Comment: Edits are done! I actually managed to make a little bit of progress by being able to call console.log(I18n.t('hello')) after importing within the second file, but the reference in the first still returns undefined. I followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/bazzel/ecdff4718962e57c2d5569cf01d332fe